# LLDP disable specific TLVs?

Tags: cisco, lldp

My techs just got a pile of fluke test equipment, which can use LLDP to determine what switchport it is connected to. However, the network guys have disabled lldp / cdp as by default it exposes the specific version of IOS that is running.

Is there a Cisco command on C3750E or C3560 series switches on IOS 12.2 to either not supply that specific TLV or have custom response independent of actual IOS version?

I have found via google references to NX-OS being able to do this with no lldp tlv-select system-desc but nothing for IOS.

Not sure which specific TLV has the IOS version in it - maybe basic TLV type 6 "System Description" or one of the LLDP-MED extensions with OUI 00-12-BB subtypes 6 or 7 ("Inventory - Firmware Revision" and "Inventory - Software Revision" respectively)

Many thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's there in later versions. 15.0 supports it on my 2960S's. And yes, `system-description` is the TLV:

```
SysDescr: Cisco IOS Software, C2960S Software (C2960S-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.0(2)SE3
```

I'm curious why the admins think hiding the IOS version is in any way a security enhancement?

[If I find the specific command reference that lists when it was introduced, I'll add a link.]

Comment: Gotcha, doesn't exist in IOS 12.2 Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can enable lldp while leaving cdp disabled, globally and per interface.  Don't know if lldp will include TLV with IOS version.

Comment: The System Description TLV includes the IOS version.